# How to install a GTK theme on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: themes, 15.04

With previous versions of Ubuntu, to install a new theme it would suffice to copy it to the `~/.themes` folder. If I do the same on Ubuntu 15.04 the theme never shows up the Unity Tweak Tool or the *Appearance* tab of the Settings tool.

What is the correct procedure on Ubuntu 15.04?

**Update**: I have tried various things following the suggestions from Sadi below. I am able to install themes with these two procedures:

1. Directly from a PPA (e.g. `apt-get install`);
2. Compiling from source and then issuing something like `sudo make install`.

So far no theme copied directly into `./~themes` or `/usr/share/theme` ever appears in the tweak tools; irrespective of folder permissions.

Comment: Have you checked the theme you've copied is complete? Otherwise it still works, but sometimes it is not listed because there's something missing, like the "unity" or "metacity-1" sub-folder.

Comment: BTW I have never seen any of the themes around other than those default ones (Adwaita, Ambiance, Radiance) ever listed in the *Appearance* section of the **System Settings**.

Comment: There is no `unity` or `metacity-1` folder in this theme, but I do not recall this being an issue with previous Ubuntu versions. Is there anything I could do to get this theme functioning? Should I simply create one of those folders?

Comment: Yes, this is something new, I think. Lately Unity DE uses the "unity" sub-folder for all window control buttons, and still requires the "metacity-1" sub-folder with at least the "*.xml" files". Without "unity" sub-folder, it fails to show window control buttons. In this case you need some manual tweak to get that theme working. For instance I sometimes symlink to another similar theme's sub-folders...

Comment: Ok, I added the `unity` and `metacity-1` folders in there, but the theme still does not appear in the **Unity Tweak Tool**.

Comment: Please compare the contents of those sub-folders you've just added with those of another theme that is listed. It might be due to some lacking "metacity-theme-<NUMBER>.xml" file.

Comment: I copied those folders from the *Ambience* theme...

Comment: Are there any other themes under `~/.themes` listed in *Unity Tweak Tool*? A permissions issue maybe? Perhaps you can test by copying this fully functional theme to that location: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318

Comment: I am precisely trying to install Vertex, I will now try to compile it myself following the instructions at GitHub. In the meantime I was able to install [a theme from a PPA](http://www.upubuntu.com/2015/05/10-best-ubuntu-1504-vivid-vervet-unity.html).

Comment: This is strange. Perhaps you can also test using a more straightforward theme like this to help identify the cause: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Azure?content=168843

Comment: Ok Sadi, even though I am not able to install themes the old fashion, I have now various themes installed by following your suggestions. Perhaps you could bundle your comments together into an answer. Thank you.

Comment: OK, done. **Vertex** (I'm currently using *Vertex-Light* at `~/.themes`) is probably the most perfect and %100 complete theme around but unfortunately has a complicated "compiling" procedure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The themes listed in **System Settings...** > **Personal / Appearance / Theme** are usually none other than *Adwaita*, *Ambiance* and *Radiance* that come with Ubuntu.

You can install other **GTK themes** (including *Window* themes) via some PPAs or manually.

PPAs usually install such themes under `/usr/share/themes` but you can also manually install themes by also copying files to `~/.themes` (or `~/.local/share/themes`) as well as copying them to `/usr/share/themes` using root privileges as PPAs do, and in either way you should be able to see and select them in **Unity Tweak Tool** or **Ubuntu Tweak**.

**Note:** *It might also be a good idea to create a **symlink** for `/root/.themes` to have GTK2 apps use the same theme also **when running as root** if you put your theme at `~/.themes`*.

Lately Ubuntu has begun using the **unity** sub-folder under a theme for window control buttons (Close/Minimize/Maximize) but it still requires the   **metacity-1** sub-folder containing at least a file named **metacity-theme-{*NUMBER*}.xml** - otherwise the theme will not be listed.

Answer (score 0):

To install themes in Linux, you can use Unity tweak tool Unity which is available in Software center.

[image]

Extract the theme file that you want to install.After extracting theme file, open terminal and move extracted folder to /usr/share/themes.

```
sudo mv path-of-extracted-theme-folder /usr/share/themes
```

When you have moved folder, open Unity tweak tool that you installed before. Click 'Themes' in Unity tweak tool and here you have the theme listed that you moved to themes directory.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend *Gnome Tweak Tool*, and I would also add that copying to `~/.themes` is also acceptable...

Comment: Why you don't recommend? Notice that I don't specify just gnome tweak, I said you can use gnome or Unity tweak tools

Comment: Yes, it's the *Tweak Tool* of *Gnome* DE as different from the *Unity* DE, and it has stopped functioning "properly" under Unity for some time now. For instance, currently under Ubuntu 15.04 you see a large "hole" so to speak in its window which simply shows either the desktop background or the window underneath, and there are also other issues. I would say the **Tweak Tool** for **Ubuntu/Unity** is either **Ubuntu Tweak** or **Unity Tweak Tool** although this may be regarded as a matter of preference if you like ;-)

Comment: Why The Downvote?

Comment: Personally, I never Down Vote ;-)

Comment: I just want the reason. For me I don't really care about reputation, I care for technical issues. I'm here for learning