# What's the proper way to install a new theme on 15.04?

Tags: themes, 15.04

I've just installed the *Greybird* theme from Ubuntu Software Centre.

But it is not available for selection in the Appearance settings. Only the standard themes (Ambiance, Radiance, and High Contrast) are shown.

It ***is*** definitely installed:

```
carl@number8:~/$ dpkg --list | grep -i greybird
ii  greybird-gtk-theme                                         1.9.4-0ubuntu2                             all          Greybird GTK2 and GTK3 themes
```

Does installing a theme via Software Centre not actually install it ready for use?

A search around this site shows that in earlier versions of Ubuntu, theme installation invovled things like :

- Knowing the difference between GTK, GTK2, GKT+, GTK3, etc.
- Unzipping an archive and copying the contents to `~/.themes`.
- Installing and running Unity Tweak Tool.
- Adding PPA repositories
- Assorted command line trickery

I have installed the theme using the Tweak Tool, but I can't help thinking that this seems like something of a hack - not the sort of thing I'd expect from an otherwise very slick and polished distro like Ubuntu.

What is the correct way to add a theme to Ubuntu 15.04?

If the three pre-installed themes are the only officially supported themes, then why is this?

I think my actual question is not so much *how* to install a theme, but why is it not as simple as a few clicks on a GUI?  i.e. Here's a list of available themes - click one and it will be downloaded and installed (c.f. Linux Mint). Is this a deliberate design policy, an oversight, or still on a to-do list?

Comment: Check whether this could help you[install a GTK theme on Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622209/how-to-install-a-gtk-theme-on-ubuntu-15-04).

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah! Back in Gnome 2.

Comment: @xangua ah :D that is me showing my age >:D

Comment: As far as I know there's only 9 themes currently that are maintained to suit 15.04 needs... They all can be found on [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html) they always try to bring themes asap in to one repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A search around this site shows that in earlier versions of Ubuntu,
>   theme installation involved things like:
>
> ```
> Knowing the difference between GTK, GTK2, GKT+, GTK3, etc.
> Unzipping an archive and copying the contents to ~/.themes.
> Installing and running Unity Tweak Tool.
> Adding PPA repositories
> Assorted command line trickery
> ```

All are the correct answers.

Using the Systems Settings -> Appearance settings in Unity desktop will indeed only show the Ambiance, Radiance and High Contrast themes.

To be able to change your theme to another one you will need to install the Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Unity Tweak Tool is a configuration tool for the Unity desktop environment.

[image]

Comment: "I have installed the theme using the Tweak Tool, but I can't help thinking that this seems like something of a hack - not the sort of thing I'd expect from an otherwise very slick and polished distro like Ubuntu. "

That's not the answer he was looking for.

Comment: @DarioSalvati I was frustrated by the same thing when trying to install a new theme in Ubuntu, and I figured out a way to get the new theme to show up in *Systems Settings* -> *Appearance*, but you don't want to do this. It's much too complicated.  Unity Tweak Tool is the easy way to do it.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think that this solution is what the OP was looking for (if there is one).

Comment: I was asking what is the proper way to install a theme, without resorting to tweak tools, PPAs, etc. It looks like the answer to that is "there isn't one", so I'll accept this. The second part of my question is **why** isn't there a way to do it?